# perl giving different result when using tr// operator

Tags: perl

Why perl is giving different result below?

```
$a = "bar";
$a =~ tr/abc/ABC/d;
print "[$a]\n"; # prints "BAr" as expected.

$x = "bar";
$y = "abc";
$z = "ABC";
$x =~ tr/\\Q$y\\E/\\Q$z\\E/d;
print "[$x]\n"; # prints "bar" to my surprise.
```

Similarly one more test case as below:

```
$p = "--aaa--";
$q = "abc-";
$r = "ABC";
$p =~ tr/\\Q$q\\E/\\Q$r\\E/d;
print "[$p]\n"; # prints "--aaa--" surprisingly.

$s = "--aaa--";
$s =~ tr/abc-/ABC/d;
print "[$s]\n"; # prints "AAA" as expected.
```

Can some body please explain this behaviour?

Best Regards,
Mohammad S Anwar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tr///` does not interpolate.

---

`tr/\\Q$y\\E/\\Q$z\\E/d` translates

- `\` to `\`
- `Q` to `Q`
- `$` to `$`
- `y` to `z`
- `E` to `E`

`$x` does not contain any of those characters, so it remains unchanged.

---

`tr/\\Q$q\\E/\\Q$r\\E/d` translates

- `\` to `\`
- `Q` to `Q`
- `$` to `$`
- `q` to `r`
- `E` to `E`

`$p` does not contain any of those characters, so it remains unchanged.

---

To get the desired behaviour, you could use

```
my %tr;
@tr{ split(//, $fr) } = split(//, $to);
$_ //= '' for values %tr;
my $re = '['.( join '', map quotemeta, keys %tr ).']';
$s =~ s/($re)/$tr{$1}/g;
```

or

```
eval "\\$s =~ tr/\Q$fr\E/\Q$to\E/d";
die $@ if $@;
```